# Web Api 2 with Mono 4.2.3

Tags: c#, .net, linux, dll, mono

I have a web api site that I have built in VS2015 and compiled on windows. This site uses a few libraries and the target platform is 4.5.2.

I take the compiled assemblies and drop them on an ubuntu linux trusty box that has the mono 4.2.3 runtime from the mono-complete deb.

The site itself is running using the OWIN self host pattern, where I have a server project built with a startup class and a separate exe project that loads it and runs it. I then try to run my project on the ubuntu box and i get the following output:

> Unknown errno: Protocol error
>   Unknown errno: Protocol error
>   Unknown errno: Protocol error
>   Unknown errno: Protocol error
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>       System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue:.ctor (string): method body is empty.

The bin directory of the service contains the System.Net.Http and the System.Net.Http.Formatting dll. I can see mono itself has GAC'ed versions of these dlls so I removed them from the bin hoping that the project would revert to using mono's own GAC but then I get loader errors because my project seems to be looking for 5.2.3.0 of those dlls not 4.0.0.0. I checked in vs2015 and I can see that those references seem to be to 4.0.0.0 so I am a little confused.

Comment: Though not 100% duplicate, it is recommended to run ASP.NET Core on non-Windows platforms, instead of using Mono, as Mono does not guarantee compatibilties.

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception is telling us what the problem is -- it looks like the method it's trying to use is not present in the Mono implementation. It could be that the .NET assemblies are still offering functions that are officially deprecated, or that it is a gap in the mono implementation.

Have you tried compiling your source using the mono compiler instead? Whilst libraries should in theory be portable they are not always in practice I have found.